# Components are not the same as it is in Vuetify

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I don't know why but when I put a component from Vuetify on my localhost it does not render as it's the website of Vuetify.

From Vuetify:
[image]

From my localhost:
[image]

I don't understand what's happening. I'm used to use Vuetify and I've never met this behavior.

```
<v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="desserts"
                sort-by="calories"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
```

Can you help me ? Why is it different ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing styles. See [getting started section](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/) in Vuetify docs on how to do it properly. Nobody here can help you unless you show some actual code and/or provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did followed the getting started section. I just did "vue add vuetify" and usually it's working without problems

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem
In fact in my App.vue I didn't put the code inside the `<v-app></v-app>`.